# Create subdomain, IIS, AWS VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis-7, server

i have an aws vm with a dns record pointing to it. my aws vm is running IIS.

i want to create a sub domain, sub.domain.com

both websites are on the same box+iis but stored in different folders..

i have tried creating a binding for the subdomain but i cant get it working..

im assuming the only changes needed are in IIS because the VM is the endpoint for that dns record and IIS should handle the rest?

Given the current configuration, what do i need to do the make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two CNAME records pointing to this VM. Then configure IIS sites to use the respective sub-domains.